# php command: exec 2 command with 1 variable

Tags: php, shell, exec

In php, I have 2 command like that (my wesite run on ubuntu os): 
cmd1:

```
exec("tmp=123");
```

cmd2:

```
$test = exec('echo $tmp');
```

Why cmd2 don't know: $tmp. How can I catch $tmp in cmd 1, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

`exec` executes an external program in it's own environment which ceases to exist after the process finishes, if you wish to pass an environment variable to a external program you need to set it using `putenv`, for example:

`putenv('tmp=123');
$test = exec('echo $tmp');`

This usage is rather strange though, you may want to re-think your design.